# Using docker registry to share my multi-image containerized app: Encountering Problems connecting multiple image repos

Tags: django, docker, nginx, devops, port

My local docker container app is made up of 4 images, React, Django, nginx, postgres. It runs perfectly locally, (although of course I need to manually go to 127.1.1.0 on my local computer to view the app)

[image: my local docker app, I can start the container by clicking a button] I want other people to be able to view this app as well, if they have docker installed on their local computer, and so, using the steps in the docker documentation, I pushed all four images to docker hub. [image: 4 separate repositories for each image as defined in the documentation best practices]

I am befuddled by the rest of the documentation, as when I tried an example using my local docker image name as below,
`docker run -d -p 3000:8000 --restart=always --name myport myport_nginx` ,

only the nginx image service was pulled,and able to start up as a single container, but the rest of the services were not called up.

Thus, my question is: How do I define those four images so that they are connected the way they are on my local computer, and so anyone with a local docker can pull my repo and inspect my app by going to 127.0.0.1 on his local computer. I know dockerbub is analogous to github and this should be straight-forward, but somehow my head has muddled this up and I would like some clarification.

Below is the dockercompose.yml file used to build the app in the first instance. I know it might be possible to modify my .yaml so that one image can call and start up all the other three, and I would like help with that if it is possible or good practice.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  django:
    
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    volumes:
      - django_static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    command: gunicorn mainapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
       - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./postgres/.env
  react:
    
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - API_SERVER=${ENV_API_SERVER}   
    volumes:
      - react_static_volume:/usr/src/app/build/static
    expose:
      - 3000
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: serve -s build -l 3000
    depends_on:
      - django

  nginx:
    restart: always
    
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - django_static_volume:/usr/src/app/django_files/static
      - react_static_volume:/usr/src/app/react_files/static
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - react
      - django

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  django_static_volume:
  react_static_volume:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's focus on a single service.  You'll need to make similar changes to all of them.

```yaml
  react:
```

```
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

This builds the `frontend` directory on your *local* system.  You need to replace this with an `image:` line pointing at your Docker Hub image.

```
      args:
        - API_SERVER=${ENV_API_SERVER}
```

This compiles in a specific URL to the image you push to Docker Hub.  Other consumers might not be able to use this.  If your `nginx` reverse proxy container already serves both the React application and the backend API on the same host and different URL paths, you might be able to use a path-only URL like `/api` and avoid configuring this.

```yaml
    volumes:
      - react_static_volume:/usr/src/app/build/static
```

This replaces the static files in your application with the contents of a named volume.  If you've modified this in some way locally, your other consumers won't have this; if you update the image, the named volume will remain unchanged and the updated files in the image won't be visible.  I'd recommend removing named volumes like this.  (Your `nginx` container will need to `COPY` the static files into its image.)

```
    expose:
      - 3000
```

This does nothing and can safely be removed.

```
    env_file:
      - .env
```

This `.env` file only exists on your local system.  You can either distribute that file or convert it to inline `environment:` variables, or depending on what the settings are, fix them with Dockerfile `ENV` instructions.

```
    command: serve -s build -l 3000
```

This overrides the image's `CMD` and shouldn't be necessary.

```
    depends_on:
      - django
```

This is fine.

After cleaning this all up, for this service I'd expect something a little more like:

```yaml
  react:
    image: 2fresh/frontend
    depends_on:
      - django
```

You may find it helpful to have a [`docker-compose.override.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files) file next to the `docker-compose.yml`.  This provides definitions that you only need for local development, such as how to `build:` the images.  The two files will be combined, and having both `build:` and `image:` together tells Compose what name to use for the built image.

```yaml
# docker-compose.override.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  react:
    build: ./frontend
    # all other settings in main docker-compose.yml file
```

Comment: Yes, the idea of your answer worked for me, which was to build a docker-compose yaml file that did not require any local dependencies, so that anyone with docker installed can use my docker-comp-yaml file and run docker compose up to get it up

Answer (score 1):

the command should be `docker-compose up`. `docker run` will only start one container. [Docker Compose up official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

Comment: I use docker composé up to build and and run the images on local docker, but how would I use docker composé to directly download and run the 4 repositories from docker hub as a single container?